# Django: Problem with saving model instances with ForeignKey-relation to database

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I would like to create and save model instances with Django.
These are my models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
...

class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
...
```

I create an order like this:

```
def store_storage_space_order(cleaned_data):
    try:
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            cleaned_data["customer_email"],
            cleaned_data["customer_email"],
            1234
        )

    customer = Customer.objects.create(
        user=user,
        first_name=cleaned_data["customer_firstname"],
        last_name=cleaned_data["customer_lastname"],
        email=cleaned_data["customer_email"],
        phone_number=cleaned_data["customer_phone"]
    )

    StorageSpaceOrder.objects.create(
        customer=customer,
        order_price=Decimal(cleaned_data["order_price"])
    )

except Exception as exc:
    logger.exception("Couldn't store any order information", exc, cleaned_data)
```

As far as I've learned, Django will save the object on calling create as well.

Trying to save the order, I get the following error message:

```
save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related customer
```

What I don't get; customer is already there and saved in the database. There are no changes on the customer in between.

Also, I've tried `customer_id=customer.id/pk,` - but both ID and PK return None.

Why is this and what do I need to change? Loading the object again is not the preferred way, as I only got the ID which marks it as unique.

Thanks for your input :)

Comment: as the error messages say the `customer` isn't saved into the database. Please do add ***complete script that you have tried*** or ***a minimal reproducible example***

Comment: Why is it then that my customer entry in the database exists? The code provided is actually what I do.

Comment: Oh... Actually, it should return a ***new `Customer`*** instance upon calling the `create()` method. BTW, do you have any ***custom model manger*** associated with the `Customer` model ?

Comment: Nope, there is no custom model manager associated. 
What seemed to work: I used Customer.objects.get(first_name="xy", last_name...) and loaded the customer again. 
But, as stated above, I can't do this, bc. the id is the only unique identifier for a customer. And this is not available on the created one.

Comment: Are you overriding any save methods on your models? Can you please share the view function/class where the customer and order are created?

Comment: Nope, I'm not overriding anything. Please find my updated code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID fields have to be auto-generated by Django, so you don't need to declare them in your models.

If you do, you override the default behaviour called when an instance of this model is created/saved.